# Can you pickup a Hint Painting Moon without having seen the painting?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

On a repeat playthrough, could you pickup a Hint Painting Moon without having possibly seen it before?

Like the paintings on the dark side of the moon, could you pick them up the first time you go through lets say the Lake Kingdom?

Can speedrunners take up those moons on the first visit, or even the "Hit the moon cube" revisit before the Hint Painting is available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, the moons aren't available until you look at the hint art. I tried this with the one near the scarecrow in the Wooded Kingdom.

[IGN's guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-odyssey/Hint_Art_Locations_and_Solutions) also indicates this is the case.

> Power Moons found through Hint Art can ONLY be revealed once the Hint Art has been read

Comment: Can confirm this as well. I know of a moon in the lost kingdom, from hint art on the dark side, and the moon won't pop out. I have unlocked the dark side (but haven't "unlocked" the hint art there yet), and have hit the moon cube in the lost kingdom.

Comment: Do you need to view the hint art, or do you just need to have unlocked the hint art in its respective kingdom?

Comment: Would guess you have to have 'read' it.